# $rootScope.apply() causing error infdig in Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have a spec on Jasmine that is firing the error :infdig when I call $rootScope.apply(), $rootScope.digest() or $httpbackend.flush(). I omitted the code for brevity, since with only this section it already fires the error:

```
describe("MyService", function() {

  beforeEach(module('my-module'));
  beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_) {
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
  }));

  describe("test", function() {
    it("it loads something", function() {
      $rootScope.$apply();
    });

  });
});
```

This simple spec is causing the error:

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

The call stack is:

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
    at angular.js:68
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:15934)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:16160)
    at Object.<anonymous> (myServiceSpec.js:10)window.__karma__.result @ debug.html:38
debug.html:25 Skipped 0 tests
```

Any ideas on why this is happening? I'm using Angular 1.4.8, with Jasmine 2.4.1.

Comment: That's not enough of code, the infinite digest is triggered in your app code not in test

Comment: Same kind of issue here with Karma and Mocha. Call to `$rootScope.$apply()` results on a timeout with angular >= 1.4. With angular 1.3 and lower, it works well. Any idea of what can cause this ?

Comment: Are you by any chance using ui-router? I ran into similar issues, and discovered that calling $apply like that (or digest, or $timeout.flush()) led to the same behavior, thanks to how I'd defined my states.